# Facebook - Why is my user_id from signed_request stored as a max integer?

Tags: php, sql, facebook, integer, max

For some reason my user_id is being stored in my database as 2147483647 rather than the actual user_id. Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
if ($_REQUEST) {
    $response = parse_signed_request($_REQUEST['signed_request'], 
                               FACEBOOK_SECRET);

    $name = $response["registration"]["name"];
    $email = $response["registration"]["email"];
    $facebookID = $response["user_id"];

    $connect = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass);
    mysqli_select_db($connect,$db_name);
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO User (U_id, U_name, U_email) VALUES ('$facebookID', '$name', '$email')") or die (mysqli_error($connect));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook user ID required more storage space,
I think you give it a integer try some other data type which have big range.
Conclusion is **Check that is your data type is integer** if `yes` then **change data type** `varchar` or else and `try again`.